# Block downloads from Google Drive Api

Tags: google-drive-api

Currently I am working on a project where it's next feature it's to block downloads on demand for a specific file/folder via API. The problem is that, I am not able to find that functionality in the docs. 
There are Permissions to change, but neither of the options are to block downloads. I also discovered an attribute called *capabilities.CanDownload*, but unfortunately is none writable attr. I kept searching but I found nothing. 
I was wondering is someone had the same issue and resolved it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the user interface you can see that download permissions can be disabled  for readers and commenters:

[image]

### To achieve the same with the Drive API, you need to use the method [Files:update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) and set the property [`copyRequiresWriterPermission`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives) to `true`

[image]

Comment: I know this solution, but the problem is that if you want the owner of the file to not to download the file, you can't do it

Comment: Unless the ownership is not transferred to another person, there is no way to limit the file owner to perform operations with his file as he pleases - after all it is his file.

Comment: okay, thanks. Now I'am having a new problem where a can't change folders attributes, only from files. Are you have having the same issue ?